# TWIG: Render Multiple blocks using extends and renderblock

Tags: php, twig

I have 2 TWIG renderblock's working on a base and standard template.  The two blocks render on the page, everything before `{% extends "base.php" %}` and after `{% block body %}{% endblock %}` in base.htm does not render, I see why as I have used `renderblock` not `render` which should render the whole template. 1 how do I get whole template to render and 2. `{% block head %}` will not render unless I use a for loop, I am sure there is a better way of doing this. Edit 1: added `$data2`.

API

```
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('event.htm');
echo $template->renderBlock('head', (array('heads' => $data2)));
echo $template->renderBlock('content', (array('events' => $data)));
```

base.htm

```
<html>
<head>
{% block head %}
{% for head in heads %}
<title>{{ head.title }}</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
    <body>
<h1>{{ head.title2 }}</h1>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

event.htm

```
{% extends "base.php" %}
{% block content %}
        {% for event in events %}
{{event.uri}}
{{event.desc}}
        {% else %}
no events! 
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

$data2

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [uri] => /event1/1 [title] => some title ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ As soon as you are rendering a block, you get the content of that block, nothing more.

You need to render the whole template using:

```
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('event.htm');

echo $template->render(array(
   'heads' => $data2,
   'events' => $data,
));
```

2/ You need to use a loop because there are big chances `$data2` contains an array or an object instead of the expected header. You should use a string instead, or know in which index you can access your header. This is difficult to help you as I don't know what does contain your `$data2` variable, but an ugly solution could be to use the [reset](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.reset.php) function this way:

```
echo $template->render(array(
   'heads' => reset($data2),
   'events' => $data,
));
```

Comment: 1/ Works. I thought this would not work as the block names are different to the array and `renderblock` had to be used. 2/ works, I am passing an array (first TWIG template, thought an array was expected).  `$data2` = `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [uri] => /event1/1 [title] => some title )`

Answer (score 0):

2/ If you know which index (in this case 0) as suggested by Alain

```
echo $template->render(array(
   'heads' => $data2[0],
   'events' => $data,
));
```